# SystemUtil.Run with Firefox mode-3 doesn't work

Tags: firefox, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

When I try to open the IE browser with mode 3 using **`QTP/UFT`**, it opens in maximized window irrespective of the last session.

```
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe", URL_Link,"","","",3
```

However, if I try to do the same for Firefox, it retains the previous state i.e. if the Firefox browser was closed in `"minimized window"` state, and if I run the below code the Firefox browser will open in minimized state.

```
SystemUtil.Run "firefox.exe","","","",3
```

I'm using Firefox version-34. UFT 12.02

Comment: Seems like a bug to me from Firefox side.

Comment: BTW, we can set Firefix to always open in maximized mode, if that is something you want to try.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr;** Looks like it's an issue with Firefox.

---

I searched the internet for the values of `mode` from UFT's documentation of `SystemUtil.Run`, for example:

> | 0 | Hides the window and activates another window. |

And found the documentation for the Win32 [`ShellExecute` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) (emphasis mine).

> `nShowCmd [in]`
>   Type: **INT**
>   The flags that specify how an application is to be displayed when it is opened. If `lpFile` specifies a document file, the flag is simply passed to the associated application. **It is up to the application to decide how to handle it**. These values are defined in Winuser.h.

I assume that UFT is using `ShellExecute` internally (this is probably why the parameters for `SystemUtil.Run` are so similar to `ShellExecute`). Then it appears that IE takes the `mode` (aka `nShowCmd`) more to heart than Firefox does.